# Rearranging TreeViewItems in a FMX TreeView

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, treeviewitem

After having tried and thought for several days I still haven't come close to an answer.
I am looking for a way to rearrange TreeViewItems in a Firemonkey TreeView, preferably by drap-and-drop. What worked in VCL doesn't in FMX. I hope there is someone who can help me get on track.
-OK apparently someone was a bit annoyed - let me rephrase: I cannot find a way te reorder Items at the same Level, so the TreeViewItems belonging to one TreeViewItem-Parent.
Can that be done?

Comment: this may be helpful: https://web.archive.org/web/20200217004903/http://monkeystyler.com/blog/entry/fixing-drag-and-drop-in-a-firemonkey-tree-view

Answer (score 1):

For items of same level. Do something like that:

```
var
  Src, Dst: TTreeViewItem;
  tmpIndex: Integer;
begin
    tmpIndex:=  Src.Index;
    Src.Index:= Dst.Index;
    Dst.Index:= tmpIndex;
end;
```

Comment: If you want to exchange items located in different branches of the tree, you have to exchange the `Src.Parent` and `Dst.Parent` too.

Answer (score -1):

The order of the items in a TTreeView depends on the order of the items in the Parents Children list.

You can modify Children list with the methods AddObject, RemoveObject, InsertObject and Sort http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject_Methods

So, to move your item to be the first use:

```
Item.Parent.InsertObject(0, Item);
```

Comment: While trying your code `Item.Parent.InsertObject(0, Item);` nothing happens in my TreeView, although I do not understand why. I did find that I can move a TreeViewItem up with `TreeView1.Selected.Index := TreeView1.Selected.Index - 1` (when Index > 0) and down with `TreeView1.Selected.Index := TreeView1.Selected.Index + 1` (when Index < Count).
In Drag-and-drop it seems impossible to pick up an Item and drop it _in between_ two siblings. It always ends up being a Child of the Sibling it was dropped on.

Comment: As I noted, nothing happens to the order of the siblings within the same level when I try  
    `TreeView1.Selected.Parent.InsertObject(0,TreeView1.Selected);`
but when I use  
    `TreeView1.Selected.ParentItem.InsertObject(0,TreeView1.Selected);`  
the order of the TreeViewItems siblings gets changed, but the selected item ends up at the bottom - despite the 0.  
I do not understand this behaviour. I hope you can help me understand the logic.

Comment: Sorry, blonde moment. Try `TreeView1.Selected.ParentItem.Items.Insert(0, TreeView1.SelectedItem);`. As for the drag/drop issue you may need to code this behaviour manually with the OnDragXXX events.

Comment: to Insert something you probably need to Remove it first from its parent (which explains the same level - aka same parent - issue). For AutoDrag situations, I noticed that you can rearrange by dropping onto the parent, which moves the control to the end of the children list (which shows on top visually - there is no separate Z-ordering in FMX as it seems)